# Count property get initialized based on other totals

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I would like to know if this makes sense.

I have a DTO Model:

```
public class CategoryListByKeywordsDetailDto : ILocalizable
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string NameEN { get; set; }
    public string NameES { get; set; }
    public string NameFR { get; set; }
    public string NamePT { get; set; }
    public int SearchCount { get; set; }
    public string ListController { get; set; }
    public string ListAction { get; set; }
}
```

and the list of it

```
public class CategoryListByBeywordsListDto
{
    public CategoryListByBeywordsListDto()
    {
        CategoryListByKeywordsDetails = new List<CategoryListByKeywordsDetailDto>();
    }

    public IList<CategoryListByKeywordsDetailDto> CategoryListByKeywordsDetails { get; set; }

    public int TotalSearchCount { get; set; }
}
```

Can I calculate in real time the `TotalSearchCount` property based on the `CategoryListByKeywordsDetails`'s list `SearchCount`'s ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do that.  You just need to implement the get method for TotalSearchCount.  Try something like this:

```
public class CategoryListByBeywordsListDto
{
    public CategoryListByBeywordsListDto()
    {
        CategoryListByKeywordsDetails = new List<CategoryListByKeywordsDetailDto>();
    }

    public IList<CategoryListByKeywordsDetailDto> CategoryListByKeywordsDetails { get; set; }

    public int TotalSearchCount 
    { 
        get
        {
            if(CategoryListByKeywordsDetails != null)
            {
                return CategoryListByKeywordsDetails.Sum(x => x.SearchCount);
            }

            return 0;
        }

        //leave out set.
    }
}
```

If you have more than one client process updating SearchCount on your Dto's then you will have a little more trouble.  If you need this to update on your client without user interaction (i.e. a refresh button) you would need to implement something to poll your database on a regular basis and push the value to client.  Much more involved, not really something that can be answered in a stack overflow question.